# Flask script url_for not found

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I have a problem. Flask application respond a 404 not found at this .css url.

[image]

How can I write this jinja code in javascript file ?

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/css/themes/') }}
```

Javascript file

```
var setColor = function (color) {
            var color_ = (App.isRTL() ? color + '-rtl' : color);
            $('#style_color').attr("href", "assets/css/themes/" + color_ + ".css");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja 2 is expected to template html files only : unless you put your script in the html and template it, which I would discourage, you cannot use templating directly in your javascript static file.

You can however template a part of the html that will contain the link, for example in a data attribute, or in a shared variable, to be recovered by javascript.

In the page

```
<div id="mydiv" data-myurl='{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/css/themes/') }}'> </div>
```

In javascript

```
 $('#style_color').attr("href", $("#mydiv").data('myurl'))
```

Comment: I learned a new thing thank you very much. its worked